# NSURL unused variable

Tags: pdf

I have generated a PDF file within my application which is saved to the Documents directory. I am trying to fetch the pdf to display within a UIWebView but i have an unused NSURL variable. Could this be the reason why the file is not loading properly? Here is my code which is attached to an IBAction button

The only way to get rid of that warning is to NSLog that NSURL. But I want to display that saved file.

This is the code I am using.

```
-(IBAction)pdf:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"client.pdf"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];

    NSString *encodedString=[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURL *webURL = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [self.myWebView loadRequest:request];
    NSLog(@"%@", webURL);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to change my filePath NSString from stringByAppendingPathExtension to stringByAppendingPathcomponent. I can now view my PDF file in my UIWebView.